# a large scale java project solution

Tags: java, ajax, jakarta-ee, ejb, frontend

I would like to start up a project from scratch. I am a java developer for years. I did even write my own mvc framework some time ago for fun. Now I am working in a company using in-house framework - which i think is a total loss of time and money. I respect the idea of  teaming up with different skilled people for a large scale project. The separation of the project is very important; Graphics guys, front end developers, software architectures, software developers, database experts, etc. I cannot risk to use a scripting language like php.

Lately, I am researching java technologies for a large scale project in every aspects. What I mean by that, for the front layer I come across with very famous technologies.

- Spring
- MyFaces
- Tapestry
- Google Web Toolkit
- Cocoon
- Velocity

Every one of them states that it is the simplest, the fastest, the latest technology and whatsoever. Of course only one them can hold the truth. I need a front end technology for fast implementation for ajax, customer/administrator security, themes, templates, internationalization, caching static pages, clustering and a support of ejb. It should also have IDE support, community support, rich documentation and online tutorials. Still I have no experience of those frameworks which to choose from. Maybe there is even better one? And most importantly, I cannot risk to start up on a technology which has development limitations. Is there any suggestions for this layer?

For the business layer, I am sure of EJB and JPA. I do even considering a web service for facade of this layer for interoperability purposes for future extensions. However, I have no idea about securing that layer (it could be applied on its web service level) which is still a problem for me. For the application server I am considering GlassFish.

And for the last question is what IDE should be picked for development. Regarding all the technologies, which are going to be used, an IDE should help me in every step, either doing the configuration for me or helping me configuring with its ready wizards. I suppose the IDE will have proper plugins for to be used technologies.

I know that I want too much, however I have a hope for a combination of technologies which will help me saving time and money in my future plans.

I ll be really glad to hear your responses, experiences for a bigger picture.

***edited:*** There is no ultimate answer, I know that. I am just taking advice. Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: *Of course only one them can hold the truth.* Actually, it's possible none of them hold the truth :-)

Comment: But usually, they all hold some part of the truth :)

Comment: "I need a front end technology for (...). It should also have IDE support, community support, rich documentation and online tutorials." - This really suits the season. Unfortunately Santa Clause doesn't do programming frameworks :/

Comment: @Jules: Upvoted for mixing Santa Clause and programming. ;-)

Comment: @Jules: santa is expected to make miracles :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm going to go out on a limb and give concrete recommendations, since I think the question can be answered.

I'll simply recommend my stack.

My stack is Stripes for the front end, and Glassfish/Java EE 5 on the back end.

Stripes is a simple Action (or MVC, whatever floats your boat), that has a small, but robust and vocal community. It has tight integration with JPA (through a plug in), a very good, and current, printer book on the topic as well as excellent reference documentation. It's main rendering tech is JSP with JSP Tags and EL.

It is not a component framework like JSF/MyFaces, so it's implementation is simpler, and it's lifecycle is simpler. It works very well with Ajax.

The key factor around Stripes, since it's based on the HTTP request cycle is that it does most of the grunge work for you, yet is very lightweight. It's easy to pick up and understand. Creating a basic Stripes app is a couple lines in the web.xml and two jars (one of which is log4j). If you can think in HTTP, then Stripes is a good fit for you.

On the back end I would simply stick with EJB and GlassFish. Java EE 6 and GFv3 are out have been out for sometime. It offers a lot of new features over Java EE 5, and GlassFish offers most any web service tech you would like to use. Java EE 6 and Spring are pretty much equal on a bullet point by bullet point basis, and since you were looking at GF, you may as well use EJB since it's there and integrated in the box. If you were using Tomcat, then Spring might be a good choice.

And, that's it. That's all you need (I dunno what you wanted Velocity for, you can add that trivially if you like, but I wouldn't use it for pages, personally, modern JSP is much better IMHO).

Glassfish will secure your web services, you can use Java EE security with your web apps, you can share logic between the back end EJBs and your web app and web services. It all works out of the box with 15 minutes of configuration to get Stripes running.

I use NetBeans, but all of the other IDEs work as well. NetBeans is nice because it come integrated with Glassfish. One less thing to configure. Download it, fire it up, and it works.

There's a Stripes plugin for NetBeans, that I don't use. I don't see a need. Once you add your few lines to your web.xml that you cut and paste from the web site, you never see Stripes again. From there, it's all simple annotations.

Unless you have a crushing need for all of the complexity and learning curve of a component framework, it doesn't get any better than Stripes, and GF w/Java EE 6 has everything you need in the box.

So, in summary: Stripes distro from www.stripesframework.org, NetBeans download from netbeans.org, and stripersist from stripes-stuff.sourceforge.net. It's a rock solid foundation that will go wherever you want to take it.

Come on by to the Stripes IRC on freenode at #stripes, and we'll answer any question you have (or hit the mailing list).

Comment: I loved your response, thank you so much for your detailed answer. It sounds really promising!

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, your question is not good. Every technology has it's bright sides and dark sides. To choose some specific technology - you need experience in all of them to estimate which problems can emerge with your project. Given your definition: `fast implementation for ajax, customer/administrator security, themes, templates, internationalization, caching static pages, clustering and a support of ejb` - 90% of frameworks support all of it either directly or using some plugins.

Moreover, various technologies are better optimized for various needs. You can't have a all-in-one-super-framework that is flawless and does everything the best way possible. Given that the framework is highly scalable and fast (example: Spring and/or Portlets) will make it hard to configure for some small tasks.

So the only thing I can recommend is to google "Java Web Framework Comparison" and hope for the best.

As about IDE, I can see only 2 choices: IntelliJ Idea and Eclipse. Again, there is no clear winner so yet again google is the only source of information you can get.

**Added:**
Talking about frameworks again, complex projects use several of them at once taking the best parts of each to aid with the specific project needs. But to do that effectively - you need to be a guru in all of the mixed technologies.

Comment: i know that all frameworks supports somehow everything. developing in shorter time is my biggest interest here and using one reliable framework can save me from most common/specific problems that can happen. i am looking for a state of the art web framework

Comment: There is no 'Art' that everybody likes. Each kind of 'Art' has it's own audience. Same goes to 'state of the art' frameworks :)

Answer (score 1):

There is almost no way that someone can actually answer this question for you. In terms of frontend technology, one of the frameworks will work for you and others won't. It all depends on which one makes sense to you. My suggestion would be to try them all out and pick the ones that you feel the most comfortable with.

With that being said, I do have a few suggestions. First, don't limit yourself to using Java. If it were me, I would use Ruby on Rails running on jRuby as the frontend as it is the fastest framework for developing web applications that I have used. By running it on jRuby, it allows you to hook into Java and let java and its libraries do all the heavy lifting on the back end. I would stay away from web services and implement things using ReST.

In terms of an IDE, definitely go with IntelliJ IDEA. It may take a little bit to get used to, but it is definitely the fastest IDE on the market. However, both Eclipse and Netbeans are also very good for Java and a tad cheaper.

Once again, the answer is, "it depends".

Comment: I am going to get my hands dirty in ruby to check it out. Only one thing, how exactly does jRuby communicate with java, or jvm, or ws-rpc (in other words, business layer)?

Comment: I didn't have anything to do with Ruby but there is also Grails (Groovy on Rails) that is made using similiar concepts to Ruby on Rails and is fully Java.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above projects started off with simple ideas.  As they gained traction, they have all added neighboring features which are useful to some but not necessarily all.  In other words, you will have to do deep analysis to pick the perfect framework.

You are not going to find a perfect match unless you just happen to be of like mind as the dozens of people working on the particular framework, assuming that all those minds were ever in perfect agreement.  The only "perfect" fit is the one you write yourself, and even then you find it's not perfect as you are limited in time and effort on developing the framework; after all, you DO have a program to write, and the framework development time competes with the program development time.

As far as IDEs go, there's differences in taste and style.  I tend to gravitate between the old standbys of Netbeans and Eclipse, and my next IDE to play with will be IntelliJ Idea.  The thing to remember is that most people commit to one IDE and then defame the rest, so you really can't get a good comparison.  IDEs take too much time to really learn for a person to give a honest unbiased opinion.  A good candidate IDE "X" will be the worst in some eyes and be the best in others.

Comment: Thank you for your answer first of all. I am not finding an ultimate answer. I was just looking for individuals' opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Given how the other answers look, I would say the biggest remaining factor is the learning curve for you and your team. Given your description of the separation of roles, your primary concern should be picking an overarching framework, such as Spring. From there, your database guys can pick whatever they want for data persistence (hibernate, jdbc, whatever) and your gui guys can pick whatever they want for their front-end (tapestry, jsf, etc.).

The primary concern I would have with such a distinct separation of roles would be the communication on the team. Make sure that their is a high degree of open communication, especially when discussing interface design, as those will be integral in the success or failure of your project (especially if you pick Spring).

As far as IDEs go, it's personal preference. The two mentioned in the other posts (Eclipse and IntelliJ) are the two I hear the most about, with Eclipse being my standard IDE for the last 4 or 5 years. I'm not familiar with IntelliJ, but I know that Eclipse has plug-ins to support Spring, Hibernate, and a host of other frameworks and ORM solutions. It also has plug-ins to support other languages as well, such as Ruby and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

"I did even write my own mvc framework some time ago for fun" - at the end of the day it may happen that you will regret that you did not stay with it. In fact the technology that is better than currently "famous" most probably is the one that will be famous a little bit later, not now. Half of your list is already "famous" as obsolete.